# Using grep to remove lines from a file, where the keys exist in another file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

I am working with 2 large CSV files. The smaller being a subset of the larger. The first field is a non-unique key, which is a customerID.

I want to find all lines from the larger file which have the same value in field 1 as the smaller file, then find the delta between this result, and the original subset.

I then want to remove all rows from the original subset which have a value in field one that exists in the delta.

In other words: I want to remove any rows from the original smaller subset which has a custromerID which also exists in a row existing in the large original file, but not in the smaller subset.

I am currently doing it like below, and I don't understand why the result is 0.

There is obviously a flaw in my logic, and this is clearly not the most elegant way to to do this, so please, I'm open to suggestions for a better way.

File: full.csv

```
,1052,tec101,UNIX
,1052,ser303,UNIX
,1052,backu2,UNIX
,1052,sma114,UNIX
,1052,appsup,UNIX
,1052,emails,UNIX
,1059,marygs,UNIX
,39835,deepr2,UNIX
,44536,hai499,UNIX
,1274,lemo27,Windows
,48567,wdanro,UNIX
,81860,pro846,UNIX
,1419,graphe,UNIX
,83999,doerf1,UNIX
,1551,taxtri,UNIX
,1572,lodes4,UNIX
,1603,wes244,Windows
,102888,law642,UNIX
,1700,au2960,UNIX
```

File: subset.csv

```
,1052,sma114,UNIX
,1052,appsup,UNIX
,1052,emails,UNIX
,1059,marygs,UNIX
,39835,deepr2,UNIX
,44536,hai499,UNIX
,1274,lemo27,Windows
,48567,wdanro,UNIX
,81860,pro846,UNIX
,1419,graphe,UNIX
```

What I'm doing now:

```
[jgalley@linux1 sandbox]$ wc -l *
 19 full.csv
 10 subset.csv
 29 total
[jgalley@linux1 sandbox]$ cat subset.csv |  awk -F, '{print ","$2","}' > subset_keys
[jgalley@linux1 sandbox]$ grep -F -f subset_keys full.csv | wc -l
13
[jgalley@linux1 sandbox]$ grep -F -f subset_keys full.csv | head -n2
,1052,tec101,UNIX
,1052,ser303,UNIX
[jgalley@linux1 sandbox]$ grep -F -f subset_keys full.csv > subset_keys_grep
[jgalley@linux1 sandbox]$ cat subset_keys_grep | awk -F, '{print ","$2","}' | head -n2
,1052,
,1052,
[jgalley@linux1 sandbox]$ cat subset_keys_grep | awk -F, '{print ","$2","}' | wc -l
13
[jgalley@linux1 sandbox]$ cat subset_keys_grep | awk -F, '{print ","$2","}' > keys_to_remove
[jgalley@linux1 sandbox]$ grep -F -f keys_to_remove subset.csv | wc -l
10
[jgalley@linux1 sandbox]$ grep -F -f keys_to_remove subset.csv > lines_to_remove
[jgalley@linux1 sandbox]$ grep -Fv -f lines_to_remove  subset.csv | wc -l
0
```

My expected result should be 7, or, without the count, the following:

```
,1059,marygs,UNIX
,39835,deepr2,UNIX
,44536,hai499,UNIX
,1274,lemo27,Windows
,48567,wdanro,UNIX
,81860,pro846,UNIX
,1419,graphe,UNIX
```

The result should be the 7 rows of the subset that have customerIDs that exist ONLY in the subset, and not also elsewhere in the full file.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're trying to do. It may help to add a concrete shortened example, like the two files in question but the short one ten lines and the long one twenty. Then indicate how you expect those files to correspond to your proposed process and result.

Comment: Okay, i'll try to come up with a more simple example, the actual files have sensitive information in them so I can't just provide a subset to play with.

Comment: Why do you exclude ",1052,sma114,UNIX", ",1052,appsup,UNIX", ... in your result?

Comment: because the key: 1052, has records in the main file that do not exist in the subset

however, 1059 should be in the result, and it wasn't so I've edited this.

Comment: But ",1419,graphe,UNIX" has records in `full.csv` too. Why is this one included in the result?

Comment: because 1419 is found only in the subset of full, not elsewhere in full. Every record in subset.csv has a record in full.csv, subset is literally just 10 records from the middle of full. what I'm trying to do is exclude records from the subset that have keys that exist elsewhere in full.csv besides the subset.

Comment: Are you saying you just want to print the lines from subset.csv that have a key field that only appears once in full.csv?

Comment: Technically, no, because if a key field existed multiple times in subset.csv, that would be okay so long as those keys didnt exist elsewhere in the full file other then the subset. I want to exclude any rows from the subset that have keys that exist elsewhere in the full file other then the subset. It doesn't matter how many times keys in the subset exist, so long as they exist only in the subset portion of the full file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I modified your input "full.csv" to remove the first 3 lines:

```
$ cat full1.csv
,1052,sma114,UNIX
,1052,appsup,UNIX
,1052,emails,UNIX
,1059,marygs,UNIX
,39835,deepr2,UNIX
,44536,hai499,UNIX
,1274,lemo27,Windows
,48567,wdanro,UNIX
,81860,pro846,UNIX
,1419,graphe,UNIX
,83999,doerf1,UNIX
,1551,taxtri,UNIX
,1572,lodes4,UNIX
,1603,wes244,Windows
,102888,law642,UNIX
,1700,au2960,UNIX
```

so your requirements stand out a bit better for the case where 1 key appears multiple times in you subset.csv file. It assumes the order of lines in the subset.csv file matches the order in the full.csv file. If that's not the case it just takes a tweak to split the strings...

```
$ cat test.awk                       
BEGIN{ FS="," }
NR==FNR { key2full[$2] = key2full[$2] $0 ORS; next }
{ key2subset[$2] = key2subset[$2] $0 ORS }
END {
   for (key in key2subset) {
      if (key2subset[key] == key2full[key]) {
         printf "%s", key2subset[key]
      }
   }
}
$ awk -f test.awk full1.csv subset.csv
,1052,sma114,UNIX
,1052,appsup,UNIX
,1052,emails,UNIX
,1419,graphe,UNIX
,44536,hai499,UNIX
,48567,wdanro,UNIX
,1274,lemo27,Windows
,81860,pro846,UNIX
,39835,deepr2,UNIX
,1059,marygs,UNIX
```

I seem to have caused some confusion by running my command on a modified input file above. Here it is on the originally so here it is running against the original file to show that it does produce the desired output:

```
$ cat full.csv 
,1052,tec101,UNIX
,1052,ser303,UNIX
,1052,backu2,UNIX
,1052,sma114,UNIX
,1052,appsup,UNIX
,1052,emails,UNIX
,1059,marygs,UNIX
,39835,deepr2,UNIX
,44536,hai499,UNIX
,1274,lemo27,Windows
,48567,wdanro,UNIX
,81860,pro846,UNIX
,1419,graphe,UNIX
,83999,doerf1,UNIX
,1551,taxtri,UNIX
,1572,lodes4,UNIX
,1603,wes244,Windows
,102888,law642,UNIX
,1700,au2960,UNIX

$ awk -f test.awk full.csv subset.csv
,1419,graphe,UNIX
,44536,hai499,UNIX
,48567,wdanro,UNIX
,1274,lemo27,Windows
,81860,pro846,UNIX
,39835,deepr2,UNIX
,1059,marygs,UNIX
```

Comment: I want to find the rows of the subset that have keys that exist ELSEWHERE in the full file OTHER then the subset. I then want to EXCLUDE these rows from the subset.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding, as the result that you got from this script is not the desired result, rows with the key 1052 should be removed from the result, not kept. Your previous one line solution actually worked properly.

Comment: I think you missed my note at the top of my answer that I modified the OPs input (and so have different output than originally desired) to highlight a requirement that meant my previous solution would not work.

Comment: But removing the first couple of lines from the input doesn't mean the requirements stand out better, it means the requirements are nill. The actual requirements have nothing to do with how many times any key appears in any of the files.

Comment: Right but every other key in the subset.csv file only appears once, hence my originally incorrect interpretation of your requirements. By removing the first couple of lines from full.csv I create a test case where a key (1052) appears multiple times in subset.csv but does not occur more than that in full.csv and that was the test case my original one-liner would not have worked for. Just try my current solution above on your originally posted input file and you'll see that it does produce the output you originally asked for.

Comment: Indeed it does, and yet, on the real world files I'm working with and not the examples, the one liner worked perfectly and the new solution did not, also, in the real world files, it will be impossible for you're proposed test case to happen, so I will use the one liner for my purposes, and mark your new solution as the answer, as it is perfect for the example case posed in this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
grep -v -f subset.csv full.csv | awk -F, '{print ","$2",";}' >keys.csv
grep -v -f keys.csv subset.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement that all records in subset.csv exist in full.csv, the following should work in bash. It first uses uniq to identify qualifying CustomerIDs from full.csv. This is then just in a join back with subset.csv for filtration.

```
join -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4 -v 2 -t, -1 2 -2 2 <(sort full.csv subset.csv | uniq -u | 
sort -k2,2 -t,) <(sort -k2,2 -t, subset.csv)
```